# How to resolve FileNotFoundException incase HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I hava an application where I am sending sms via POST method, This method working fine but some time giving FileNotFound Exception. Please any one tell me Whats the problem.

Below is my code. Thanks

```
 public static String sendSMS(String data, String url1) {
            URL url;

            String status = "Somthing wrong ";
            try {
                url = new URL(url1); 
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
                connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(data.getBytes().length));
                connection.setUseCaches (false);

                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
                wr.writeBytes(data);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
                connection.disconnect();

                // Get the response
                try {
                    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                    String s;
                    while ((s = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                        status = s;
                    }
                    rd.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                status = "MalformedURLException Exception in sendSMS";
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                status = "IO Exception in sendSMS";
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return status;
        }
```

The Error What I got

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://.... at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1401)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You disconnected the connection before reading the input stream. Move this line of code:

```
connection.disconnect();
```

To a point ***after*** you have read the response stream.

Comment: Hi Perception, I moved the code after response stream but after that I am getting FileNotFoundException Can you tell me why this happening.... any Idea?... This Exception happen about 10 out of 100

Comment: @Narendra - you might want to post a separate question, with sufficient detail (current code sample, exception stacktrace).

Comment: Hey Perception, I am getting Exception like: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://.... at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1401)

Comment: @Narendra - hop into [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25008/how-to-resolve-filenotfoundexception-incase-httpurlconnection) when you can.